# Extracting a list of objects that exist in another list objects using linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

Linq noob here.

I have `IList<Product>` ApplicableProducts and a `IList<Product>` CurrentProducts.

I need to return a new `IList<Product>` of all CurrentProducts that exist in Applicable products.

I understand I need to be working with .Contains and .Any but getting a little lost.

Any tips appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx

```
var intersection = list1.Intersect(list2);
```

or

```
var intersection = list1.Where(i => list2.Contains(i));
```

Comment: Calling `Intersect` should be faster for large collections.  (It uses a hashtable)

Comment: @SLaks: Yeah, I was going to speculate on that, but I wasn't sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Can be done without LINQ. Here:

```
var identical = applicableProducts.Intersect(currentProducts);
```

You may also want to supply your own `IEqualityComparer`.

Comment: That is using linq.  `Intersect` is defined in the `System.Linq` namespace.